# codeigniter cron job not routing to specified controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using cron job in CI but instead of redirecting to cron controller(schedular) the cron job is redirecting to default controller(content). Following are the code:

```
routes.php
$route['schedular'] = "schedular/index/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "content/index/$1";

cpanel cron code
/opt/php54/bin/php /home/server_name/public_html/demo/cron.php schedular index
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing `index` from cron command

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, solved the problem as suggested by @Viral. Following is cron command.

```
/opt/php54/bin/php /home/server_name/public_html/demo/index.php schedular
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to point your cron task on controller and its function that you want to run directly instead of redirecting from any where else